# react-geosuggest issue Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'prop-types'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, node-modules

I'm having trouble releasing my application on Azure when it comes to use `webpack`.
The following error is thrown when run on the server.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-geosuggest/module/prop-types.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'prop-types' in 'd:\a\1\s\some\project\node_modules\react-geosuggest\module'
 @ ./node_modules/react-geosuggest/module/prop-types.js 7:17-38
 @ ./node_modules/react-geosuggest/module/Geosuggest.js
 @ multi moment react-geosuggest react-bootstrap react-overlays ./Scripts/React/Components/Oem
```

and I don't see/know what exactly the issue is.

On the other hand - locally - it's running/building without any issues. So I'm really stuck at this point.

This is what my dependencies (in `package.json`) look like:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "moment": "^2.19.2",
    "react": "15.6.1",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.6.0",
    "react-addons-transition-group": "^15.6.0",
    "react-dom": "15.6.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "0.31.5",
    "react-geosuggest": "2.7.0",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "pathval": "1.1.0"
}
```

In antoher project where I use `react-geosuggest` it's working/building without any complains.

I've already tried to use the latest version of `react` & `react-dom` as well as adding `prop-types`. But still the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and solved it by adding this to my dependencies section in package.json:

```
"prop-types": "^15.6.1"
```

followed by rerunning:

```
yarn install
```